# How to cancel Places SDK for Android find autocomplete predictions task?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying figure out how to cancel the task which was created to fetch autocomplete predictions using the new Places SDK for Android.

The task was created using this code -

```
Places.initialize(applicationContext, ApiClient.GOOGLE_API_KEY)
placesClient = Places.createClient(this)

placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request).addOnSuccessListener { response ->

   for (prediction in response.autocompletePredictions) {
        Log.i(TAG, prediction.placeId)
        Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPrimaryText(null).toString())
    }


}.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
    if (exception is ApiException) {
        val apiException = exception as ApiException
        Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + apiException.statusCode)
    }
}
```

The task has a addOnCancelledListener but no way to cancel it!

How do I cancel this task?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to cancel it manually. I found class `zzu<TResult>` which is the class that extends `Task<TResult>`. `zzu` can cancel it so I assume cancelation happens automatically.

Comment: You're probably referring to CancellableTask<TResult>. However its not present in the places sdk at all. In fact I only see that its present in the firebase storage package. The lack of a cancel method seems like such a bad way to design the autocomplete api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the complete code to cancel an autocomplete search request following the links shared by @Riyasa

```
/* 
Create a new CancellationTokenSource object each time you execute a new query 
because the cancellation token received from this will work only for this request 
and not afterwards 
*/

val cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource()

val requestBuilder = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
        .setQuery(newText) //NewText is your query text
        .setCancellationToken(cancellationTokenSource.token)
//Setting the cancellation token from the object created above

placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(requestBuilder.build()).addOnSuccessListener { response ->
   //Do what you need to with the result
}

//and finally call this to cancel the request using the object created for this request
cancellationTokenSource.cancel()
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can use getCancellationToken () method to cancel any yet-to-be-executed requests.

You can follow official places sdk document from the following link.
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest#getCancellationToken()

An example on how to use the cancellation token:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/CancellationToken